# how to replace c(xxx) with c(xxx) in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to replace `c(xxx)` with `c(xxx)` in `preg_replace`?

In the code bellow, I want to replace `str c(xxx)` with `functioun c(xxx)`.
I fail to get the correct result I want .
What is wrong with my code ? and how to fix?

```
$c['GOOD']='very good';
$c['BOY']='jimmy';
function c($x){
    global $c;
    if(isset($c[$x])){
        return $c[$x];
    }
}

$str="hello c(GOOD) world c(BOY) ";
$str=preg_replace("@c\(([A-Z_\d]+)\)@",c('$1'),$str);
echo $str;  // --> hello  world

// how to get hello very good world jimmy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `e` modifier http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> **Note:** This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.5.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

```
<?php
  $str  = preg_replace( "/c\(([A-Z_\d]+)\)/e", 'c("$1")', $str );
?>
```

Better use `preg_replace_callback`

```
<?php
  $str  = preg_replace_callback( "/c\(([A-Z_\d]+)\)/", function( $m ) {
    return c( $m[1] );
  }, $str );
?>
```

Comment: no, don't do this. The `e` modifier is deprecated and considered bad practice. All recent PHP versions supply the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function instead.

Comment: -1, `e` modifier is deprecated in php5.5: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval

Comment: yes, but recommending a deprecated feature still is a -1 in my book

Comment: even before it was formally deprecated, it was considered incredibly bad practice. It takes all the bad stuff about `eval()` and makes them worse.

Comment: Added `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: my php is 5.2 , it too high for my version

Comment: @mingfish_004 - if you're on PHP 5.2, you need to upgrade. They dropped support for 5.2 over two and a half years ago. If hasn't had any security fixes in all that time, and there are known security issues with it. You need to ugprade. Even 5.3 is nearly at the end of its life now.

Answer (score 3):

[php.net: preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)

If you look at example #2, that is what you are looking for :)

```
function c($matches){
   print_r($matches)
}
$str = preg_replace_callback("@c\(([A-Z_\d]+)\)@", 'c', $str);
```

Small sidenote: I dont know if you want to call your function 'c', but I suggest clear functionnames which explain what they do

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_replace_callback with [Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
<?php
$c['GOOD']='very good';
$c['BOY']='jimmy';

$str="hello c(GOOD) world c(BOY) ";
  echo preg_replace_callback('@c\((.*?)\)@', function ($match) use ($c) { 
   if (isset($c[$match[1]])) return $c[$match[1]]; 
  }, 
  $str);
?>
```

The advantage of this function is: it allow you to pass second parameter see `use ($c)`. Then no need to create second function.